Does triggering component renders during animation frame wait til frame is done, or synchronously reflow/paints then finish the frame callback?
I've seen a few similar-ish questions but I'm struggling to find a definitive answer - any advice appreciated!
Consider:

you have a react component
you have an animation loop running via requestAnimationFrame(update), outside of the component (it's controlled by a singleton class accessible to the component)

Then:

in a single frame, which runs update exactly once, the react component is re-rendered twice
this is done by the singleton firing an event which the component receives in a useEffect and then calls forceRender to re-render it

What happens:

The browser interrupts the update execution in order to synchronously perform re-layout and re-paint as soon as the component finishes the re-render (so this would happen twice in the single frame)

The browser schedules the re-layout and re-paint each time the comp performs a render, but this only actually happens once the update function has finished execution

Something else?


I would like to think that the re-renders are scheduled to come into affect at the next layout/paint cycle, but I need to be sure because otherwise I'll need to take pains not to result in more than one potential redraw each frame...

Why is the component rendered twice per frame? It's not clear how the animation loop affects your component exactly or what you mean by "singleton", please share your code as a [mcve]

Hi @Bergi, I've made some edits that will hopefully make things clearer without the need to write any code!

No it's still not clear why you think the component renders twice, if the singleton event just forces one re-render (I assume through some useState or useReducer). Concrete code really would help.
